# how to find,open, read, and modify an existing node(robot_state_publisher node) in ros?

Tags: ros, turtlebot-gazebo, node, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have downloaded the turtlebot simulator and i run the command rxgraph to see the nodes. I want to find and modify two of them (robot_state_publisher, robot_pose_ekf). is it possible?? how??

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/30694/how-to-find,open,-read,-and-modify-an-existing-node(robot_state_publisher-node)-in-ros?/) by [Penny](https://answers.ros.org/users/1547/penny/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2012-03-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you want to modify files, I would suggest not finding the debian installed versions, but instead doing a from-source checkout and creating an overlay. Modifying system files is generally a bad idea.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2012-03-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Searching the ROS wiki isn't a bad idea.

If you're looking for the files themselves, roslocate and roscd are the tools you want.

---

Originally posted by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) with karma: 4119 on 2012-03-28

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1